# Reactjs SVG icons size varying inspite of same css

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is the first time i am using reactjs to build a website.
I have been using the reactjs icons from the react icon library. These icons are varying in size when repeated in a same section of the website. Attached the photograph for your reference'.
I checked using the inspect. it shows
for smaller icons it comes as path 9.97x9.97 but for normal appearing icons it comes out to be 14x14. Not sure what path means neither I am clear why the icons size is varying

JSX Code is (sample )

```js
import React from 'react'
import './exp.css'
import { AiOutlineCheckCircle } from 'react-icons/ai'

const Exp = () => {
  return (
    <section id='exp'>
      <h5>Skills & Qualifications</h5>
      <h2>My Experience</h2>
      <div className="container exp__container">
        <div className="exp_english">
          <h3>English Literature</h3>
          <div className="exp__content">
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
                <h4>Shakespearian Literature</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>American Literature</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Oxford Grammer</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
             <div>
             <h4>Poetry Writing</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
             </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Critical Analysis</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
        

{/* END OF ENGLISH LITERATURE */} 
        <div className="exp_pyschology">
        <h3>Pyschology</h3>
          <div className="exp__content">
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Counselling</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Coaching</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Research</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Advisory</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
            <article className='exp__details'><AiOutlineCheckCircle className='exp__details-icons'/>
              <div>
              <h4>Teaching</h4>
              <small className='text-light'>Mastered</small>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section >
  )
}

export default Exp
```

```css
.exp__container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    gap:2rem;
}

.exp__container > div {
    background-color: var(--color-blueish-pink);
    padding: 2.4rem 4rem;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    transition: var(--transition);

}

.exp__container > div:hover {
    background-color: var(--color-bluegreen-transparent);
}

.exp__container > div h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.exp__content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    row-gap: 2rem;
}

.exp__details {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.exp__details-icons {
    margin: 0.8rem;
    color: var(--color-gray);
    font-size: 1rem;

    

}

/* ================ MEDIA QUERIES (MEDIUM DEVICES) ============================== */
@media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    .exp__container {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .exp__container > div {
        width: 80%;
        padding:2rem;
        margin:0 auto;
    }

    .exp__content {
        padding:1rem;
    }
}

/* ================ MEDIA QUERIES (SMALL DEVICES) ============================== */
@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .exp__container {
        gap: 1rem;
    }

    .exp__container > div {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 2rem 1rem;
        margin:1rem;
    }
}
```

Check the first icons in the image it looks completely out of sync
[image: Image of Issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by Flex. Either wrap the icons with a div or add `flex-shrink: 0` to `.exp__details-icons` class.

```
<article className="exp__details">
    <div>
        <AiOutlineCheckCircle className="exp__details-icons" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Shakespearian Literature</h4>
        <small className="text-light">Mastered</small>
    </div>
</article>
```

[image]